# How to inject a variable in a string in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is my one of my tries without sucess:

```
var myVar VARCHAR;
exec :myVar:= 'm';
select * from users where lower(name) like lower(':myVar%')
```

`myVar` is the variable i want to inject in the string

Hope to have explained my question well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cant write a variable in quotes first clear this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the variable inside the quotes:

```
select * from users where lower(name) like lower(:myVar) || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

```
var myVar VARCHAR2(2); --varchar2, not varchar
exec :myVar:= 's%'; -- put the wildcard here, it's just easier

select * from employees where lower(first_name) like lower(:myVar)
```

run everything via F5

[image]

Comment: This is perhaps very correct because it reduces the seperate concatenation and takes in the input initiallization itself